# What are these weird stains on motherboard? Is there any chance this motherboard is brand new?

Tags: motherboard

I recently bought a (brand new) Gigabyte X570 Aorus Ultra motherboard and I discovered some weird-looking stains (looks like glue residue) and I have been told that it is most probably flux residue.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I contacted Gigabyte support but they were extremely unhelpful and ambiguous. They said that unless I send them the motherboard, they cannot give me any information and I should contact the supplier.

If you are experienced with hardware and motherboards, do you think that this board could indeed be brand new? Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE**

The stains shown in the pictures are not the only ones on the board. These are just the ones that I could photograph with my phone through the case.

Comment: Matte black solder resist is "_great_" for showing this sort of imperfection... The marks on the PCB itrself are indeed likely flux or some other residue from cleaning. The marks on the heatspreder / heatsink look more like general scratches, but could be a thin plastic film that is often used to keep these shiny parts "_pristine_"... have you tried removing something like this?

Comment: @Attie Yes, there was a plastic film which I removed. The scratches were underneath. Thoughts?

Comment: My only suggestion would be that this isn't a premium product with a lot of care and attention going into perfect, super-clean and shiny surfaces... It's nothing to worry about, and doesn't indicate that the board isn't "_brand new_"... it's just a number of very minor (but perfectly acceptable) defects... frustrating as that may be.

Comment: That kind of shiny metal is hard to keep pristine, and is largely for cosmetics. the plastic would likely have been to prevent major gouges during assembly but minor imperfections would be normal due to the bending and cutting done on the piece. If you genuinely are not happy with the board then you should replace it, but minor cosmetics are difficult to avoid.

Comment: @Attie This is a Gigabyte Aorus X570 Ultra and I paid ~$350 for it. My understanding is that this falls in the 'premium' umbrella, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Mokubai I would have replaced it if that were possible, but unfortunately I have strict deadlines for the next 4 moths and can't go through the process of replacement. Especially since I bought the board from an online store from a different country. I'm just trying to figure out if I was cheated or not and are seeking the advice of professionals such as you. A lot of people have said that this does not look new to them and this is why I'm trying to make sure I have as much information as possible.

Comment: @Soutzikevich I don't mean to confront or offend, but there are levels ([~£300](https://www.scan.co.uk/products/gigabyte-x570-aorus-ultra-amd-x570-am4-ddr4-pcie-40-triple-m2-2-way-sli-crossfire-intel-gbe-wifi-usb) vs. [~£720](https://www.scan.co.uk/products/gigabyte-x570-aorus-xtreme-amd-x570-am4-ddr4-pcie-40-triple-m2-2-way-sli-crossfire-10g-gbe-wifi-usb))... I don't think it would be too unreasonable for the ~£720 board to be in this condition either.

Comment: Like @Mokubai, I also do a lot of work with electronics design and prototyping, and I don't think this is unreasonable. It sounds like the question you're really asking is "_has this board been damaged and then re-sold to me? Might it fail soon?_", to which I'd say: these marks alone do not imply or indicate that this is the case.

Comment: @Attie Okay, so it is not a premium board and this happens. You and Mokubai have actually made me feel a little better. However, I got contradicting answers from other people, such as [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/gpc92x/stains_on_brand_new_motherboard_look_like_flux/frl8e11?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) and [this](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/weird-stains-on-motherboard-cant-figure-out-if-this-is-brand-new-or-not-gigabyte-x570-aorus-ultra.2581123/post-40176399). I guess I will have to contact the supplier and see how it goes.

Comment: @Soutzikevich - Most modern motherboards PCBs are several layers (i.e. more than 3).  This could be discoloration, water damage, flux, or even a sign that Gigabyte repaired the board at some point.  I can tell you even a new motherboard can have defects, I recently purchased one of the most expensive 9th Intel MSI boards on the market, and the board refused to turn on.  Turns out there was a short, within the socket, to GND preventing the board from even attempting to POST.  I sent the motherboard to MSI, it was repaired/replaced, and the motherboard works flawlessly.

Comment: If the motherboard works, and there isn't anything that is setting off the "this isn't right" alarms, other than these spots it should be fine.  Only alternative is to send it to Gigabyte and have them look at it, but if your timeline does not allow for that, it might not be worth the trouble for them to troubleshoot spots on the motherboard.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for sharing. When I contacted Gigabyte they told me that they don't repair motherboards and they only sell brand-new products. They declined to comment on the photos I sent them for some reason. [The reviews](https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.computeruniverse.net) of the supplier are extremely bad and there are other people that say they have received used products instead of new. Anyway, I'll ask the supplier if they are willing to replace this in 4 months.

Comment: @Soutzikevich - I don't know what you asked Gigabyte but I know they provide warranty work on their motherboards.  Which means that Gigabyte either throws away product when it's sent in for warranty work or repairs those products.

Comment: It turns out Gigabyte eSupport is different than Gigabyte Support. They have just replied and told me that it is absolutely **NOT NORMAL** for a brand-new board to have those scratches/stains. Anyway, thanks for your time, now you know too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all the forums I have posted, the majority of experts have said that this is not normal for a new board. It looks like the "wisdom of crowds" concept applies here, because Gigabyte themselves have just verified that this is not normal for a new board.

This was Gigabyte's reply:

> Dear *****,
>
> Of course it is NOT normal for a new board to have such scratches/ stains (residue).
>
> You should return it to local store where they sold you as new.
>
> Best Regards,
>
> GIGABYTE

Comment: Please add this to your question by editing it.

Comment: This is the answer to the question and it was provided directly from the manufacturer, so we know it is as accurate as possible. Since the actual answer cotnradicts what was said in the comments and in the only other answer, it is close to logic to post the answer as an answer. @Valay_17 Your comment makes no sense